# Having content security policy issue with scrapy and splash

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

What I am doing is

1. Google for some linkedin specific links
2. Login to linkedin.com (successful)
3. Revisit home page (it fails here)
4. Extract some the the desired  info from links I googled in first step

My scrapy bot fails at step 3. So my questions is, Is there any way to bypass this content security policy? If its please share your thoughts in detail thanks.

One of the related issue google points me to are   [CSP header](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/313)
 and [Eval Issue](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/undercrawler/issues/62), put that is not helpful as it does not provide any details about proxy setup.

> 2017-12-29 10:59:47 [scrapy_splash.middleware] WARNING: Bad request to
>   Splash: {u'info': {u'source': u'[string "..."]', u'message': u'Lua
>   error: [string "..."]:32: JavaScript error: EvalError: Refused to
>   evaluate a string as JavaScript because \'unsafe-eval\' is not an
>   allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy
>   directive: "script-src \'report-sample\'
>   \'sha256-[redacted...]=\'
>   \'unsafe-inline\' static.licdn.com s.c.lnkd.licdn.com
>   static-fstl.licdn.com static-src.linkedin.com
>   https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/service-worker-push.js
>   https://platform.linkedin.com/js/analytics.js static-exp1.licdn.com
>   static-exp2.licdn.com s.c.exp1.licdn.com s.c.exp2.licdn.com
>   static-lcdn.licdn.com s.c.lcdn.licdn.com https://www.linkedin.com/sc/
>   https://www.linkedin.com/scds/ https://qprod.www.linkedin.com/sc/
>   https://www.linkedin.com/sw.js
>   https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/abp-detection.js".\n', u'type':
>   u'LUA_ERROR', u'line_number': 32, u'error': u'JavaScript error:
>   EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
>   \'unsafe-eval\' is not an allowed source of script in the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src \'report-sample\'
>   \'sha256-[redacted...]=\'
>   \'unsafe-inline\' static.licdn.com s.c.lnkd.licdn.com
>   static-fstl.licdn.com static-src.linkedin.com
>   https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/service-worker-push.js
>   https://platform.linkedin.com/js/analytics.js static-exp1.licdn.com
>   static-exp2.licdn.com s.c.exp1.licdn.com s.c.exp2.licdn.com
>   static-lcdn.licdn.com s.c.lcdn.licdn.com https://www.linkedin.com/sc/
>   https://www.linkedin.com/scds/ https://qprod.www.linkedin.com/sc/
>   https://www.linkedin.com/sw.js
>   https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/abp-detection.js".'}, u'type':
>   u'ScriptError', u'description': u'Error happened while executing Lua
>   script', u'error': 400} 2017-12-29 10:59:47 [scrapy.core.engine]
>   DEBUG: Crawled (400) https://www.linkedin.com/feed/ via
>   http://localhost:8050/execute> (referer: None) 2017-12-29 10:59:47
>   [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400
>   https://www.linkedin.com/feed/>: HTTP status code is not handled or
>   not allowed

Comment: Have you seen this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/313)?

Comment: @Casper I already linked that in my question, although that seems to be not helpful, add extra complexity to equation